# Alternate to DECODE like function to be used in elsif statement in PLSQL procedure

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql

I am trying to use a condition `elsif` where something like decode needs to be used so that the condition is true and insertion is made. I am doing this in a procedure and condition is like

```
elsif ((v_DIVIDEND/Divisor)-1 < ABS(0.2)) then 
    insert into table(Divisor,b,c) values(Dividend,y,z);
```

It works fine when the divisor is not zero but when the divisor is zero it fails. I want to rule out zeroes in divisor using like another nested if condition within `elsif` or something like decode. I tried another `if` but syntax seemed to be wrong. Using `Decode` says it can only be used in SQL statement. Any suggestions, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also handle the "divisor equal to zero" exception and made the insert if the error occurs, see samples code in handling "divisor equal to zero" exception,

Sample 1: This sample defines a divisor_equal_to_zero exception

```
DECLARE
    divisor_equal_to_zero EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(divisor_equal_to_zero, -1476);
    v_divisor NUMBER := 0;
    v_quotient NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_quotient := 1/v_divisor;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Print A: '||v_quotient);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN divisor_equal_to_zero THEN
        v_divisor := 1;
        v_quotient := 1/v_divisor;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Print B: '||v_quotient);
        --you can put the insert statement here
END;
/
```

Sample 2: This sample use the pre-defined ZERO_DIVIDE exception

```
DECLARE
    v_divisor NUMBER := 0;
    v_quotient NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_quotient := 1/v_divisor;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Print A: '||v_quotient);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
        v_divisor := 1;
        v_quotient := 1/v_divisor;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Print B: '||v_quotient);
        --you can put the insert statement here
END;
/
```

Comment: There's no need to define your own exception, there is a predefined `ZERO_DIVIDE` exception

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on what you want to get as a result when divisor = 0 (i.e. something *large* or something *small*), you can use something like this:

For small result (divide by 1E99):

```
case when divisor = 0 then 1E99 else divisor end
```

For large result (divide by 1E-99)

```
case when divisor = 0 then 1E-99 else divisor end
```

As of you being unable to use DECODE: that's correct, it can be used ONLY within the SELECT statement. It means that you should rewrite your code and put everything into SELECT (which is probably a bad idea). So - try CASE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a condition like this to check if `Divisor` is zero.

```
elsif ( Divisor !=0 )  and  ((v_DIVIDEND/Divisor)-1 < ABS(0.2))
THEN 
insert into table(Divisor,b,c) values(Dividend,y,z)

elsif Divisor = 0 
THEN
insert into table(Divisor,b,c) values(?,?,?);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `nullif`:

```
declare 
    divisor constant integer := 0;
    result number;
begin
    result := 100 / nullif(divisor,0);
end;
```

Here `divisor` is replaced with null if it has the value `0`, giving the `result` as null.